# Getting a CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite, android-sqlite

I have an application where the user enters data in a form, and can then view it in a table. Records can be selected in the table, causing that record to be loaded into the form where it can be edited or deleted. I am getting the following error message in Logcat,

```
android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 requested, with a size of 0
```

in response to this cursor query,

```
edRowid.setText(c.getString(0));
```

Relevant Logcat output and code are below,

Logcat:

```
2022-08-02 09:30:08.630 5783-5783/net.pearl.GoldenBB E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: net.pearl.GoldenBB, PID: 5783
android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 requested, with a size of 0
    at android.database.AbstractCursor.checkPosition(AbstractCursor.java:468)
    at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.checkPosition(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:136)
    at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.getString(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:50)
    at net.pearl.GoldenBB.dataEdit.selectedTableRecord(dataEdit.java:223)
    at net.pearl.GoldenBB.dataEdit.onResume(dataEdit.java:173)
```

Code:

```
  private void selectedTableRecord(){
    DBAdapter msdb= new DBAdapter(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),MainActivity.szDbName, null);
    db=msdb.getWritableDatabase();
    if(MainActivity.szSelectedRow == null){
       resetForm();
    }else{
        Cursor c = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM surveyDB WHERE _id ="+MainActivity.szSelectedRow,null);
        c.moveToFirst();
EditText edRowid = (EditText) getView().findViewById(R.id.edRowidxml);
        edRowid.setText(c.getString(0)); //THIS IS LINE 223, WHERE FATAL EXCEPTION OCCURS
    c.close();  
    }
    db.close();
}
```

This code actually works fine when editing and updating records, however deleting a record results in the described error. Thanks in advance for useful insight and perspective.

**UPDATE:** Curiously, changing the column number from zero to one,

```
edRowid.setText(c.getString(0));
```

to this,

```
edRowid.setText(c.getString(1));
```

Causes the cursor query to run. Note that (0) is rowid whereas (1) is a data field.

**UPDATE #2** Application also runs fine if I change the cursor query from this,

```
    edRowid.setText(c.getString(0)); 

to this,

    edRowid.setText("0");
```

What is odd is that there are several other columns that do cursor queries (c.getString("n")) and populate correctly. Column zero is rowid.

Comment: What is `MainActivity.szSelectedRow`? Is it a string or an integer?

Comment: Returns a string that is the rowid of the record selected in the table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ... with a size of 0

means that the query did not return any rows.

This is why you should not just call `moveToFirst()`, which returns `true` if there is a first row or `false` if there is none, but check its value:

```
private void selectedTableRecord(){
    DBAdapter msdb = new DBAdapter(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.szDbName, null);
    db = msdb.getWritableDatabase();
    if (MainActivity.szSelectedRow == null) {
       resetForm();
    } else {
        Cursor c = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM surveyDB WHERE _id = ?", new String[] {MainActivity.szSelectedRow});
        if (c.moveToFirst()) {
            EditText edRowid = (EditText) getView().findViewById(R.id.edRowidxml);
            edRowid.setText(c.getString(0)); 
        } else {
            // do something
        }
        c.close();  
    }
    db.close();
}
```

I also used a `?` placeholder for the parameter `MainActivity.szSelectedRow` and passed its value in the 2nd argument of `rawQuery()`, because this the recommended and safe way to pass parameters.

Comment: You nailed it. Thanks.